# Match only by values in mongodb and return id of the document

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, api, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have inserted some json data into mongodb and I wanted to perform a simple search by matching only the values irrespective of the keys (Since keys are different for different documents) and wanted to return the id of the document. I don't know how to compare only by values in mongodb.

Example: Suppose if am searching for word "Knowledge" it should return all the ids of the document which contain the word "Knowledge" irrespective of its key value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Wildcard Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes).

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a static superset of fieldnames, you may find [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-indexes) and the [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#text) query operator useful for word-based searches.

Create the text index on every potential field, and those contained in each document will be included.